# Converting Docker create command into docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to convert this to a DockerFile, and have no idea where to start, could someone help me out please?

```
docker create --name=<NAME> --restart=always -p <PORT>:<PORT> -e PUID=1001 -e PGID=1001 -v /dev/rtc:/dev/rtc:ro -v /var/lib/<dockerInstance>:/config -v /mnt/<My_Vol_1>:/mnt/<My_Vol_1> -v /mnt/<My_Vol_2>:/mnt/<My_Vol_2> -v /mnt/<My_Vol_3>:/mnt/<My_Vol_1> -v /mnt/<My_Vol_4>:/downloads <dockerInstance>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you gave, what you need is not a Dockerfile but a docker-compose file. Your command here creates a container which needs an image to be able to run.

A Dockerfile allows you to creates an image that contains a set of instructions.
A Docker compose file allows you to run this image (or multiple images) with multiple parameters like the ports to expose.

In your case, it could be :

```
version: "3.9" 
services:
  <NAME>:
    image: <IMAGE>
    container_name: <NAME>
    ports:
      - "<PORT>:<PORT>"
```

You can use `docker compose up` after that to run your container.

It's not the complete file to convert your command but it's a good way to start.
See here for the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) about the docker compose.